# Why: appengine to firebase Authentication fails with error referer forbidden

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, web-applications, firebase-authentication, gcloud

I have this web app project which I deploy on a google cloud appengine.

```
gcloud app deploy
```

The appengine is basically just a webserver serving static files. But I had to use the appengine for prerendring the website for SEO.

In the webapp, I use the firebase authentication API. 
https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.8.0/firebase-auth.js

In firebase console, I activated the anonymous authentication. 
[preview of firebase auth providers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S46kE.png)

When I deploy a new version of my static content on the appengine, I create a new version named "stag" only to preview and test everything before deploying to production. I can then preview my work on the version specific url which is something like this:

```
https://stag-dot-frb-proj1.appspot.com/
```

frb-proj1: is my firebase project id.

When I preview my work on the url: https://stag-dot-frb-proj1.appspot.com/
I got the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Requests from referer https://stag-dot-frb-proj1.appspot.com/ are blocked.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Requests from referer https://stag-dot-frb-proj1.appspot.com/ are blocked.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

I spotted the error in the chrome dev tools on the network tab. It happens when the app tries to access the following url:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=AIza....CcpT0
```

I assume this api call if for creating a new anonymous user on the firebase auth api.

All the used domains are authorized in the firebase console as expected.

**Authorized DOMAINS**

- frb-proj1.firebaseapp.com
- frb-proj1.web.app
- stag-dot-frb-proj1.appspot.com
- frb-proj1.appspot.com

## Tried solution

I tried to follow this example https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/authenticating-users-firebase-appengine

And setup the environment variable **FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID** in my **app.yaml** for the appengine

## QUESTION

Any idea what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering this error, it seems that this problem is related to your API Key. As per these other similar cases - that you can access in the below links - it seems that the API Key configured doesn't have all the needed permissions.

I would recommend you to take a look at the below cases and give it a try on the solutions informed there - all of them informed that it solved their problems.

- [Requests for referrer are blocked when trying to sign in anonymously to Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54072206/requests-for-referrer-are-blocked-when-trying-to-sign-in-anonymously-to-firebase)
- [firebaseui Internal error: {"error":{"code":403,"message":"Requests from referer  are blocked.","errors":{"message":"Requests from referer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/pK5-hKG9VMs)
- [App hosted on firebase does not have access to firebase authentication? PERMISSION_DENIED](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/xLE2Z6vYYG0)

Let me know if the information helped you!