# Firebase signInWithEmailAndPassword throws PERMISSION_DENIED on Brave Browser

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, brave-browser

When using Brave Browser with "Shields up", calling Firebase's signInWithEmailAndPassword throws a 403, "Request from referer https://www.googleapis.com/ are blocked." (typo on 'referer' courtesy of Firebase).

Anyone managed to get around this? I've seen people adding www.googleapis.com to the list of restricted referrers allowed, but that seems unsafe. See last comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59542362/13630418

It seems that using signInWithPopup avoids the problem, but this flow isn't ideal.